# How to Duplicate a Folder with a new (today) Creation Date in macOS Finder?

Tags: macos, date, directory, paste, finder

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uyba.jpg)

I would like to duplicate a folder with the current date set as the "Created Date".

How can I achieve that?
What would be the fastest way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do

```
touch -mt YYYYMMDDhhmm your_folder
```

example

```
touch -mt 201804121200 your_folder
```

after ls -al to see the result or just select the folder and do command+i

Hope that will help.